# How do you get the url of a website that's linking your images?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, http, python-requests

I'm trying to allow only certain websites/domains link my images. I'm doing this using Laravel's middleware.

At the moment I can only get it to work on the URL hosting the laravel app.

Here is the code that I have attempted to use. The If statement is supposed to check if the URL using the image is in the AuthorisedDomains table.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $authDomains = AuthorisedDomains::pluck('domain');
//        dd($request->getHttpHost());
        if ($authDomains->contains($request->getHttpHost())) {
            $request->headers->set('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return Image::make(public_path('images/forbidden.png'))->response();
        }
    }
```

At the moment it only works for localhost or anything that the app is hosted on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check the referer: `Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')`.

`$request->getHttpHost()` returns the hostname your app is running on as you have already noticed.

Maybe take the [X-Forwarded-For](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header into account too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Decided it's easier to do it using the IP address using `$request->getClientIP();` I did try using the suggestion but no one can be bothered to add all variations of their domain so it's easier to do IP.

Comment: @Brennii96 The client IP won't be much use to you.

Comment: Got this working. went back to @Olivenbaums answer I'll just add all variations of a domain